# Nearest neighbor search in n-dimensions

Tags: performance-tuning

Suppose a list of items such as:
 `L1 = RandomReal[{0, 100}, 1000];`

I need to find the position of each k-neighbor in the original list. And very quickly if possible.
As we can see, the problem is divided into two main parts :
- The search for k-neighbors.
- The search for their positions in the original list.

***Mathematica code***

---

*On Mathematica 9.0*

Doedalos :

```
KPosition1[x_, y_] :=
  Block[
        {step0, step1, step2},
         step0 = Range[1, Length@x, 1];
         step1 = (Nearest[x, x[[#]], y][[2 ;; -1]]) & /@ step0;
         step2 = Map[Position[x, #][[1, 1]] &, step1, {2}]
       ];


KPosition2[x_, y_] :=
  Block[
        {step0, step1, step2},
         step0 = Thread[x -> Range[1, Length@x, 1]];
         step1 = Nearest[step0 , #, y] & /@ x
       ];
```

Bill s :

```
KPosition3[x_, y_] :=
  Block[
        {step0, step1, step2},
         step0 = Thread[x -> Range[1, Length@x, 1]];
         step1 = Nearest[step0];
         step2 = Map[step1[#, y][[2 ;; -1]] &, x]
       ];
```

*On Mathematica 10.0*

kale :

```
KPosition4[x_, y_] :=
  With[
       {p = PositionIndex[x]},
        Map[p[#][[1]] &, Nearest[x, x, y][[All, 2 ;; -1]], {2}]
      ];
```

Mr.Wizard :

```
KPosition5[x_, y_] := Nearest[x -> Range@Length@x, x, y];
```

***Benchmarking***

---

Warning : Only Kposition1, Kposition2 and Kposition3 are tested.

1) By varying the length of the lists.

[image]
[image]

2) By varying the dimension of the points.

[image]
[image]

***Commentary***

---

*On Mathematica 9.0*

Sort by execution's speed :
Kposition3 > Kposition2 > Kposition1

*On Mathematica 10.0*

If somebody wants to make the benchmarks... Currently, I has not the version 10 of Mathematica.

Answer (score 16):

You can speed it up by only invoking the `NearestFunction` once:

```
KPosition3[x_, y_] := 
  Module[{step0, step1, nf}, 
   step0 = Thread[x -> Range[1, Length@x, 1]];
   nf = Nearest[step0];
   step1 = nf[#, y] & /@ x];
```

Running your three timing tests gives:

```
{0.003057, 0.004344, 0.051009}
```

Comment: Is it possible to show the dynamics of the search process via a suitable graph?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do not think it's possible to be faster with a simpler code.

Comment: I suspect that it is almost always possible to find faster and simpler code!

Answer (score 9):

Here's a way using `Nearest` a little differently, remembering `Nearest`'s second argument can be a list...

```
KPosition[x_, y_] := With[{p = PositionIndex[x]}, 
 Map[p[#][[1]] &, Nearest[x, x, y][[All, 2 ;;]], {2}]]
```

And my timings:

```
KPosition[Tst1, 8]; // AbsoluteTiming
KPosition[Tst2, 8]; // AbsoluteTiming
KPosition[Tst3, 8]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.00255016, Null}
>
> {0.0201945, Null}
>
> {0.103676, Null}

Comment: I'm seeing a ~3% speedup using WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision in Nearest[] in your implementation of KPosition[].  Varying Method and DistanceFunction had no oveservable improvement.  (Octrees were substantially worse.)  3% may not be sufficient for the OP.

Answer (score 5):

*Edit: now including Michael E2's improvement.*

Building on your own code and the existing answers this seems both cleaner and faster:

```
wizKP[x_List, n_] := Nearest[x -> Automatic, x, n]
```

Comment: I will made new benchmarks soon...

Comment: Actually, when I try to test your code I have the following error :
" Nearest :: dmtch : The dimension of ... and ... does not match"

Comment: @Doedalos A limitation of version 9 perhaps.  Please tell me what you get from `Nearest[Thread[x -> Range @ Length @ x], x, n]` ?

Comment: I have the same error. I think you're right about Mathematica 9. I see nothing in the documentation of version 9, which mentions the possibility of using a list in second position. This is not the case in the documentation of version 10. I think, it is time for me to change.

Comment: Shouldn't `Nearest[x -> Automatic, x, n]` work?

Comment: @Michael I completely forgot about that syntax.  Thanks.